# Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac error

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an android project which was able to build successfully before updating Android Studio. I left this app aside for around two months and during these period I worked with flutter projects and updated the Android Studio along with gradles. Now I need to update some content in this app but cannot build.

Error 1
`D:\Paokholloi New by TheD\customerapp\app\src\main\java\com\paokholloi\customers\activity\StripePaymentActivity.java:111: error: cannot find symbol Card card = cardInputWidget.getCard(); ^ symbol:   method getCard() location: variable cardInputWidget of type CardInputWidget`

Error 2
`D:\Paokholloi New by TheD\customerapp\app\src\main\java\com\paokholloi\customers\activity\StripePaymentActivity.java:113: error: cannot find symbol if (!card.validateCard()) { ^ symbol:   method validateCard() location: variable card of type Card`

Please help me.

This is the StripePaymentActivity.java

```
    package com.paokholloi.customers.activity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.paokholloi.customers.R;
import com.paokholloi.customers.constants.BaseApp;
import com.paokholloi.customers.constants.Constant;
import com.paokholloi.customers.json.ResponseJson;
import com.paokholloi.customers.json.StripeRequestJson;
import com.paokholloi.customers.json.fcm.FCMMessage;
import com.paokholloi.customers.models.Notif;
import com.paokholloi.customers.models.User;
import com.paokholloi.customers.utils.SettingPreference;
import com.paokholloi.customers.utils.api.FCMHelper;
import com.paokholloi.customers.utils.api.ServiceGenerator;
import com.paokholloi.customers.utils.api.service.UserService;
import com.stripe.android.ApiResultCallback;
import com.stripe.android.PaymentConfiguration;
import com.stripe.android.PaymentIntentResult;
import com.stripe.android.Stripe;
import com.stripe.android.model.Card;
import com.stripe.android.model.ConfirmPaymentIntentParams;
import com.stripe.android.model.PaymentIntent;
import com.stripe.android.model.PaymentMethodCreateParams;
import com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Objects;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class StripePaymentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button mSubmitBt;
    private CardInputWidget cardInputWidget;
    private Stripe stripe;
    private String price;
    RelativeLayout rlnotif, rlprogress;
    TextView notif;
    ImageView back_btn;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stripe_payment);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        price = i.getStringExtra("price");
        initView();
        rlprogress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        startCheckout();
        getinitAction();

    }

    private void getinitAction() {
        final User user = BaseApp.getInstance(this).getLoginUser();
        StripeRequestJson request = new StripeRequestJson();
        request.setUserid(user.getId());
        request.setPhone_number(user.getNoTelepon());
        request.setPrice(price);

        UserService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(UserService.class, user.getNoTelepon(), user.getPassword());
        service.intentstripe(request).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseJson>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseJson> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseJson> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                        rlprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        initAction(response.body().getData());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseJson> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    public void notif(String text) {
        rlnotif.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        notif.setText(text);

        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> rlnotif.setVisibility(View.GONE), 3000);
    }

    private void initAction(String client) {
        mSubmitBt.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {
            Card card = cardInputWidget.getCard();
            if (card != null) {
                if (!card.validateCard()) {
                    notif(getString(R.string.check_carddata));
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                notif(getString(R.string.check_carddata));
                return;
            }
            rlprogress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            PaymentMethodCreateParams params = cardInputWidget.getPaymentMethodCreateParams();
            if (params != null) {
                ConfirmPaymentIntentParams confirmParams = ConfirmPaymentIntentParams.createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(params, client);
                final Context context = getApplicationContext();
                stripe = new Stripe(
                        context,
                        PaymentConfiguration.getInstance(context).getPublishableKey()
                );
                stripe.confirmPayment(this, confirmParams);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initView() {
        mSubmitBt = findViewById(R.id.submit_bt);
        cardInputWidget = findViewById(R.id.card_iw);
        notif = findViewById(R.id.textnotif);
        rlnotif = findViewById(R.id.rlnotif);
        rlprogress = findViewById(R.id.rlprogress);
        back_btn = findViewById(R.id.back_btn);

        back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startCheckout() {
        SettingPreference sp = new SettingPreference(this);
        PaymentConfiguration.init(
                getApplicationContext(),
                sp.getSetting()[15]
        );
        stripe = new Stripe(
                getApplicationContext(),
                Objects.requireNonNull(sp.getSetting()[15]
                ));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        stripe.onPaymentResult(requestCode, data, new PaymentResultCallback(this));
    }

    private class PaymentResultCallback implements ApiResultCallback<PaymentIntentResult> {
        @NonNull
        private final WeakReference<StripePaymentActivity> activityRef;

        PaymentResultCallback(@NonNull StripePaymentActivity activity) {
            activityRef = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull PaymentIntentResult result) {
            final StripePaymentActivity activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }

            PaymentIntent paymentIntent = result.getIntent();
            PaymentIntent.Status status = paymentIntent.getStatus();
            if (status == PaymentIntent.Status.Succeeded) {
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
                String data = gson.toJson(paymentIntent);
                try {
                    JSONObject respone = new JSONObject(data);
                    success(respone.get("id").toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } else if (status == PaymentIntent.Status.RequiresPaymentMethod) {
                rlprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                notif(getString(R.string.payment_failed));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
            final StripePaymentActivity activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }
            rlprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            notif(getString(R.string.error) + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void success(String id) {
        final User user = BaseApp.getInstance(this).getLoginUser();
        StripeRequestJson request = new StripeRequestJson();
        request.setUserid(user.getId());
        request.setPhone_number(user.getNoTelepon());
        request.setId(id);
        request.setName(user.getFullnama());

        UserService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(UserService.class, user.getNoTelepon(), user.getPassword());
        service.actionstripe(request).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseJson>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseJson> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseJson> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(StripePaymentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        Notif notif = new Notif();
                        notif.title = "Topup";
                        notif.message = "topup has been successful";
                        sendNotif(user.getToken(), notif);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseJson> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendNotif(final String regIDTujuan, final Notif notif) {

        final FCMMessage message = new FCMMessage();
        message.setTo(regIDTujuan);
        message.setData(notif);

        FCMHelper.sendMessage(Constant.FCM_KEY, message).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull okhttp3.Call call, @NonNull okhttp3.Response response) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull okhttp3.Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

build.gradle (:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('D:\\Edit\\paokholloi\\customerapp\\customerapp.jks')
            storePassword '123456'
            keyAlias '123456'
            keyPassword '123456'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.paokholloi.customers"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 100
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation('com.mikepenz:fastadapter:2.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ornolfr:rating-view:0.1.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1-jre'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.7'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.7'
    implementation 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
    implementation 'me.everything:overscroll-decor-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.4.0'
    implementation 'net.the4thdimension:audio-wife:1.0.3'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.yesterselga:country-picker-android:1.0'
    implementation 'com.labo.kaji:fragmentanimations:0.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.6.0'
    implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.2.0"
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-java:5.36.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-geojson:5.8.0-beta.2'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:5.5.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places-v9:0.12.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-markerview-v9:0.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: There's not enough information here. We don't have the code for the classes involved. If you've updated some dependencies and they have updated their APIs then you'll have to update your code as well. Refer to the documentation for those APIs.

Comment: Please paste all stacktrace red lines and wrap it in a code block.

Comment: @Michael sir, this error was happened before updating any dependencies, and I tried by updating too. Error is same. I checked the "Show Quick Fixes" option from the "Problems" tab. It ask to rename reference.